# pullback of closure of closed subspace under a Banach space embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$, $Y$ be two Banach spaces, and $X \hookrightarrow Y$ a continuous embedding. Let $A \subset X$ be a closed subspace. Let $\overline{A}$ be the closure of $A$ in $Y$ under the norm of $Y$. Then is it the case that $\overline{A} \cap X = A$?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  For example, let $X = L^\infty([0,1])$, $Y = L^1([0,1])$, with the natural inclusion map.  Take $A = C([0,1])$ which is closed in $X$.  But $A$ is dense in $Y$, so $\overline{A} = L^1([0,1])$, and $\overline{A} \cap X = X$.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful.